# Add data from a form to an email C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

[image]I am developing a project,an example is like the image, where the user enters their data in the form and when you press the email button you have to get that email to a person that I have already written in my code, but also in that email you have to insert the data of the person that was entered in the textboxes, this data has to be, as you know, in the body.

The problem is that I do not know how to load that textbox data into the mail.

This is the mail code:

```
|System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(); 

        msg.To.Add("mail from that person"); 
        msg.From = new MailAddres("system_mail@",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); 


        msg.Subject = "Project";
        msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;


        msg.Body ="**Here you load the user data, which are the textbox** ";
        msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; 
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false; 


         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); 
         client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("system_mail@", "password");

         client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true; 
        try
        {      
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: I'd ditch that empty catch block ASAP. At least log the exception if you're going to bother catching it.

Comment: Hint: `msg.Body += txtName.Text;`

Comment: `msg.Body = $"Name: {textBoxName.Text}, Age: {textBoxAge.Text}, Occupation: {textBoxOccupation.Text}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reference the names of the textbox in you `msg.Body` variable, i.e.:

```
msg.Body = $"You entered {name.Text}, {age.Text}, {occupation.Text}";
```

if `name`, `age`, and `occupation` are the names of your textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the values in the textboxes.

```
    msg.Body =txtName.Text+" "+txtAge.Text+" "+txtOccupation.Text;
```